# Flutter image save and share problem using packaages

Tags: flutter, image, save, share

i try to save and share saved picture. I am using share_plus ve and image gallery saver package.
I can succesfuly saved picture but i can not access saved image. I can see saved image in gallery.

PS : I am using android emulator.

This is my save code.

```
Future<String?> _saveImagee(Uint8List imageBytes) async {
try {
  
  await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(imageBytes);

  
  Directory tempDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String tempPath = tempDir.path;
  String imageName = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
  String imagePath = '$tempPath/$imageName';

  return imagePath;
} catch (e) {
  print('Error saving image: $e');
  return null;
}
```

}

and this one is share method.

```
void _shareImage(String imagePath) async {
try {
  final file = File("$imagePath"); 

  if (await file.exists()) {
   
    await Share.shareXFiles(
      [XFile(file.path)],
    );
  } else {
    print('File not found.');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('Error sharing image: $e');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here you are just giving a temporary directory where Image is not present.
You can get the path object in the result like bellow.

```
final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
        imageBytes,
       );
```

try using `result["filePath"]`

and print it to see it.

Please note that the exact path would be

```
final imagePath = result['filePath'].toString().replaceAll(RegExp('file://'), '');
```

As you need to remove `file://` from the front to exactly know where it is saved.